# PowerBI - Treemap to show elements alphabetically

Tags: powerbi, dax, treemaps

I have a Treemap visualization which seems to show the table rows in reversed alphabetical order:

[image]
(Top Level. Notice "A" is at the bottom right while "W" is on the top left)

Just to prove it is not a coincidence when it is drilled down one level:

[image]
(Notice "D" is on the far right while "R" is on the far left)

According to Microsoft, [Treemap is one of the visuals where the elements cannot be sorted](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-change-how-a-chart-is-sorted/). Does anyone have a suggestion as to what can be done about it?

Answer (score 1):

Treemap will always default to sort by the value, highest to lowest. The top left element of a tree map will be the highest value and all other elements in the tree map will be arranged by value flowing down from the top.

How equally sized numbers are ordered and arranged will be determined by a "best fit" algorithm that distributes the elements in the visual.

That's what they mean with "the elements cannot be sorted".

If you would like that sort algorithm to change, you can put in a post at the [Uservoice site for Power BI.](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/6802457-uservoice)

As an aside: If you find that Tree Maps are not doing what you want to show, consider that you may not be using the correct visual. Tree Maps are about ordering different sized elements by size. If all your element are the same size and you want to shoe them in a specific order, then Tree Maps is not the right tool for the job.